# Only one Button is drawn on screen

Tags: python, button, pygame

When I define a button like this

```
onebut = ButtonCPyg()
onebut.giveOpt(x=0,y=0,width=400,height=200,action = helloW) # hello word
onebut.changeText("Hello","coolFont.otf",25,(0,0,0))
onebut.changePic("thepic.png","thepicOver.png")
```

It's working fine. I can display it whith `.display()` and the `.listen()`-Method works also.

But the problem is, when I define the second button ...

```
onebutt2 = ButtonCPyg()
onebutt2.giveOpt(x=200,y=600,width=400,height=200,action = helloWW)
onebutt2.changeText(newText="Hello",newFont="coolFont.otf",newSize=25,newColor=  (255,255,255))
onebutt2.changePic("thebutt.png","thebuttO.png")
```

... there is only one single button on the screen.

I can "listen"  to actions but when I click on it there are for example two lines of "Hello Word"

That means that my code is't working with two or more buttons.

There is my button class :

```
class ButtonCPyg:
    #so Main class

    def __init__(self):
        #init method
        ###BUTTON'S parameters
        ButtonCPyg.butX = 0
        ButtonCPyg.butY = 0
        #
        ButtonCPyg.width = 0
        ButtonCPyg.height = 0
        ##
        #TEXTin 
        ButtonCPyg.text = ""
        ButtonCPyg.textFontL = "coolFont.otf"
        ButtonCPyg.textSize = 0
        ButtonCPyg.textColor = (0,0,0)
        #
        ButtonCPyg.pic = None
        ButtonCPyg.picOver = None
        ##
        ButtonCPyg.action = None


    #TEXT
    def changeText(self,newText="",newFont="",newSize=0,newColor=(0,0,0)):
        #change text things
        ButtonCPyg.text = newText
        ButtonCPyg.textSize = newSize
        ButtonCPyg.textColor = newColor
        ButtonCPyg.textFontL = newFont

    def text_objects(self,text ,font,color):
        #text objects
        textSurface = font.render(text,True,color) 

        ##returns
        return textSurface , textSurface.get_rect()

    def message_display(this_object,text,x,y,n,color):
        #text types
        largeText = pygame.font.Font(ButtonCPyg.textFontL,n)

        ##Surfafce and text
        TextSurf , TextRect = this_object.text_objects(text ,largeText,color)
        ##specifies
        TextRect.center = (x,y)
        #Blitting
        mainc.gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf,TextRect)
    ##give things

    def giveOpt(self,x=0,y=0,width = 0,height = 0,action = None):
        #givit
        ButtonCPyg.butX = x
        ButtonCPyg.butY = y
        ##
        #
        ButtonCPyg.width = width
        ButtonCPyg.height = height
        ##ACTION
        ButtonCPyg.action = action


    ##Button things
    def changePic(self,picString,picOString):
        #change options
        #try and str for safe
        try:
            #
            ButtonCPyg.pic = pygame.image.load(str(picString))
            ButtonCPyg.picOver = pygame.image.load(str(picOString))
            #
        except Exception, e:
            #if error do nothing
            pass

    ##blitt it and read actions
    def display(self):
        #display it overly things
        mousePos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        #if over mouse
        if ButtonCPyg.butX + ButtonCPyg.width > mousePos[0] > ButtonCPyg.butX and ButtonCPyg.butY + ButtonCPyg.height > mousePos[1] > ButtonCPyg.butY:
            #then blit it 'overly'
            mainc.gameDisplay.blit(ButtonCPyg.picOver,(ButtonCPyg.butX,ButtonCPyg.butY))
            #text on it
            design.message_display(ButtonCPyg.text,ButtonCPyg.butX-ButtonCPyg.width/2,ButtonCPyg.butY-ButtonCPyg.height/2,ButtonCPyg.textSize,ButtonCPyg.textColor)

        else: #if not
            #blit it normaly
            mainc.gameDisplay.blit(ButtonCPyg.pic,(ButtonCPyg.butX,ButtonCPyg.butY))
            #text on it
            design.message_display(ButtonCPyg.text,ButtonCPyg.butX-ButtonCPyg.width/2,ButtonCPyg.butY-ButtonCPyg.height/2,ButtonCPyg.textSize,ButtonCPyg.textColor)



    ##action listen
    def listen(thing):
        #listen if click
        mousePos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        #if over mouse
        if ButtonCPyg.butX + ButtonCPyg.width > mousePos[0] > ButtonCPyg.butX and ButtonCPyg.butY + ButtonCPyg.height > mousePos[1] > ButtonCPyg.butY:
            #then listen it 'overly'
            thing.action()

        ##

    def helloW(anarg):
        print("Clicked"))
```

There is my full game loop:

```
##GAME loops
def mainLoop():
    #Main game loops . Set run True
    mainc.isRunningMain = True



##Widgets
    oneba = ButtonCPyg()
    oneba.giveOpt(x=0,y=0,width=400,height=200,action = helloW)
    oneba.changeText("Hello","coolFont.otf",25,(0,0,0))
    oneba.changePic("thepic.png","thepic.png")

    onebb = ButtonCPyg()
    onebb.giveOpt(x=200,y=600,width=400,height=200,action = helloWW)
    onebb.changeText(newText="Hello",newFont="coolFont.otf",newSize=25,newColor=(255,255,255))
    onebb.changePic("thebutt.png","thebuttO.png")

    #while run run
    while mainc.isRunningMain:
        #event handle

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            ##qquit

            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                ##then quit
                mainc.isRunningMain = False

            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                #then list mousbdownact
                oneba.listen()
                onebb.listen()


        ##displays
        #bg
        mainc.gameDisplay.fill((0,0,0))
        ##
        design.headEr()
        oneba.display()

        onebb.display()
        ####UPDATE
        pygame.display.update()
        #tick the cloclk
        mainc.fpsEl += 1

        ##TIME
        if mainc.fpsEl == mainc.fpsCur:
            #then add to time
            mainc.timeEl += 1
            ##
            if point.point + point.income <= point.storage:
                #then add points
                point.point += point.income

            ##else
            else:
                #then not add it
                point.macSt = True

            #print(mainc.timeEl)
            #set it back
            mainc.fpsEl = 0
        #
        mainc.clock.tick(mainc.fpsCur)
```

Comment: maybe use `self.` instead of `ButtonCPyg.` .When using `ButtonCPyg.avariable` it's actually referring to the static context of the class and not of the instance of your object. That's why your objects are sharing those containers to store their data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Hacketo posted, the problem is that when you call for instance

```
 ButtonCPyg.butX = 0
```

you use so-called [***class attributes***](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#instance-objects), which are **owned by a class itself** and **shared by *all* instances of a class**.

This means, **when you create a second Button** (i.e. a `ButtonCPyg` instance), **you override all your class attributes** of your `ButtonCPyg` class: both buttons have the same parameters and are displayed at the same position on your screen.

To avoid this problem you should use [***instance attributes***](http://www.python-course.eu/python3_class_and_instance_attributes.php), which are **owned by a specific instance of a class**. You can use the `self.` prefix  to declares this type of attribute: change all  `ButtonCPyg.attribute_name`  to `self.attribute_name`:

```
 self.butX = 0
```

Hope this helps :)